# How to delete aggregated row in ui-grid without using $templateCache

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I have a ui-grid which consists of an aggregated empty row.I want to delete this aggregated row.I have achieved this by using $templateCache. But the change is affecting other pages wherever there is ui-grid.So I want to delete an aggregated row without $templateCache.

Answer (score 0):

Used gridApi.grid.registerRowsProcessor and registered a row processor which sets the row visibility to false based on condition.

```
$scope.gridApi.grid.registerRowsProcessor(function(rows){
     _.each(rows,function(row){
        if(row.groupHeader == true && row.dispNm == ' '){
             row.visible = false;
        }
     });
    return rows;
},1000);
```